# I am getting rvm: command not found after installation of rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, sproutcore

I know the above question is very common question. I have gone through multiple posts on this topic. But I didn't get any resolution.

I have installed rvm locally. We already have the installation files. SO went into the folder and run the install command.

```
$ ./install
```

Then I checked ./rvm folder in the Users home folde

```
$ cd ~/.rvm
```

folder exists. Hence Installation is successful.

Now I am typing rvm in the command line

```
$ rvm
```

I am getting below exception

```
$ rvm
-sh: rvm: command not found
```

After reading the multiple articles in stackoverflow on this issue, I learned that I have to add the below lines in .bash_profile as I am using Mac OSX 10.7.3

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Even after I am getting same exception while typing rvm. Is there any thing extra I need to do? or Am I missing some thing? Please help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Steps to try out:

1. Log out and login to your system.
2. Open a new terminal and manually run

> source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

then

> rvm

Check these work-arounds.

### Update:

To avoid running

> source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

every time you open a terminal, include this line into `~/.MacOSX/environment` in your Mac (This is similar to `~/.bashrc` in GNU/Linux-based systems under `$home` aka `~` directory).

Comment: I have tried with the above specified steps. How ever I am getting "-bash: $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory" while running the command "$ source '$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm'". And after that if I run rvm in terminal still I am getting the specified exception. Please help

Comment: @Ramesh please post your rvm installation directory path.

Comment: @Ramesh irrespective of the installation path, if your rvm was installed correctly, then run `source path_to_rvm_directory/scripts/rvm`. It should run the script `rvm` and then type the command `rvm`.

Comment: It is working. Thank you. Earlier I have run with quotes source '$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm'. Now I have run with out quotes. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your on time support. Really appreciated

Comment: For me, it was `source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm` that worked.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, i am using  Ubuntu Bash in Windows 10 and to fix the problem i used:

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: This solved my problem when setting up RVM in Docker

Answer (score 5):

For those that are doing this in 2018 just 
add

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

to your .bash_profile within your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

you need to enable login shell in terminal emulator preferences, sometimes it is needed to use `/usr/bin/bash --login`, here is an example https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

after enabling login shell you need to close terminal application and open it fresh.

Comment: This is the solution for an entirely different issue where the rvm command is found but the user will receive the error `RVM is not a function`. It is also not sometimes but either-or. The user should either change the terminal preferences and reopen the terminal or issue `bash --login` in which case terminal reopen is not needed but it is a 1-time solution only.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to open a new Terminal session.

After I installed it using:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
rvm install 2.2
```

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 18.04, I had to run the command below to solve the issue after **rvm** was installed using [instruction from here](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm).

```sh
source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of other options available for RVM:

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```